# как в React js передать свойство элементу onClick или onKeyUp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

вчера начал смотреть React JS, создал скрипт, который просто добавляет на страницу таблицу с input'ами. Но мне надо на эти импуты еще повесить событие, я их прописываю, но когда запускаю страницу, таблица отображается, а вот сами события у импутов нет. Как можно их добавить?

Мой скрипт react.js

```
'use strict';

ReactDOM.render(
<table class="table_report">
<tr>
  <td class="td_report">
    <div id="popup">
      <div id="popup_bg" />
      <div class="form">
        <p for="inp" class="inp">
          <label>
            <input type="text" id="road" placeholder="&nbsp;" onKeyUp="searchfield(this.id)"/>
            <span class="label">Дорога назначения:</span>
            <span class="border" />
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

на выходе получаю элемент . То есть, почему он удаляет событие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из приведенного вами кода могу сказать следующее

Во первых для того чтобы  **JSX** элементам добавить событие их пишут не в двойных кавычках как у вас а таким образом.

```
onKeyUp={searchfield(this.id)}
```

Во вторых это плохая практика так не впихивайте все в внутрь `ReactDOM.render`-а.
Создавайте отдельные компоненты и добавляте их.Так учитсья надо  используя правильные практики так проще и читать и поддерживать ваш код.

В третьих у вот этого тега

```
 <span class="border" />
```

должно быть закрывающий `span`

В четвертых классы в **JSX** пишутсья не так  `class="inp"` а `className="имя класса"`

В пятых **React** всегда если какой то элемент не рендеритсья на страницу то об этом сообщает соответсвенной ошибкой в консоли в первую очередь смотрите туда.

Comment: Большое спасибо за указанные ошибки, буду дальше практиковать. Самое интересное, он мне все отобразил верно и без ошибок в консоле и все классы подтянул из css.